# How to write sql query to sort topics by date and then by number of likes?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, structure

I want something like 9gag or reddit have.

```
SELECT * 
FROM topic 
WHERE somecondition 
ORDER BY posted_time DESC, number_of_likes DESC?
```

I have number of likes, number of favorited and number of comments. I also wish to have that popularity algorithm for not more than 30 hot topics per day, and if there is no topic at all for that day then to automatically drop to the next day and give me popular topics and so on. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your statement at the end 'LIMIT 30', that'll limit the results to 30, and it'll give you the topics according to your order in the query.

So your query should look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM topic 
WHERE somecondition 
ORDER BY posted_time DESC, number_of_likes DESC LIMIT 30
```

Also, please realize if all of your topics are stored with the time posted, it is highly unlikely that you will have multiple topics from the same time, meaning that the likes will not take affect. If you want to order it by day and then by likes, perhaps change the query to `ORDER BY DATE(posted_time)`